# Best way to aggregate with mongodb in variable json structure

Tags: json, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a number of reports that are built in the following json structure
Date/Country/Vendor where the Date/Country/Vendor are variables and the actual data is stored at the leaves of this json tree.

For example a simplified json would look at follows

```
 {
   "1/2/2001" :
   {  
     "DE": {
            "Vendor A" : { 
                          leaf data... 
                          revenue:123213
                          }
            "Vendor B" : { 
                          leaf data... 
                          revenue:123213
                          }
            }
   }
```

Now, lets say I want to aggregate the revenue. Is there way fast way to do this with the Mongo's aggregation framework or am I tied to doing three nested for loops.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Not with this structure, unfortunately.  Your document structure makes the paths unknown.  You'd be advised to make the document standardized and move those unique keys from the object name to a property and use arrays instead.

Comment: Thanks @EliGassert. I see how this would work. Each array entry is a  [Date:X, Country: y, Vendor: z, data: { revenue: 12321}]

Comment: Right.  If you did it that way, then you can easily walk the "data.revenue" document and aggregate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you could structure your JSON to this :

```
{
    "date": "1/2/2001",
    "country": "DE",
    "vendors": [
        {
            "vendor": "Vendor A",
            "leafdata": "xxx",
            "revenue": 123213
        },
        {
            "vendor": "Vendor b",
            "leafdata": "xxx",
            "revenue": 123213
        }
    ]
}
```

Then its easy with aggregation framework, you can have a query like following :

```
[{
    $unwind: '$vendors'
},
{
    $group: {
        _id: '$country',
        revenue: {
            $sum: '$vendors.revenue'
        }
    }
}]
```

This would give revenue for all countries that you have in your collection.

Note: I used date as string only, but i would recommend to use ISODate.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this feature in the agg framework is planned. See https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-5947

You still have the ability to use map reduce.